# Where is wrong with my STUN Binding request

Tags: stun

I send udp request to `stun.l.google.com:19305`, but I don't get any response from google stun server. I omit all of the error check in this piece of code. My program hang in `recvfrom`.

```
int stun_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in stun_client;
memset(&stun_client, 0, sizeof(stun_client));

stun_client.sin_family = AF_INET;
stun_client.sin_port = htons(local_port);

int rc = bind(stun_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&stun_client, sizeof(stun_client));

struct sockaddr_in stun_server;
memset(&stun_server, 0, sizeof(stun_server));

stun_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
stun_server.sin_port = htons(remote_port);
inet_pton(AF_INET, server, &stun_server.sin_addr);

typedef struct stun_header_tag {
    uint16_t message_type;
    uint16_t message_length;
    unsigned char transaction_id[16];
} stun_header_t;

stun_header_t header;
header.message_type = htons(0x0001); /* Binding Request */
header.message_length = htons(0);
*(int *)(&header.transaction_id[8]) = 0xFFEEFFEE; /* transaction id in the response should keep consistent with this one */

rc = sendto(stun_socket, (void *)&header, sizeof(header), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&stun_server, sizeof(stun_server));

char response[64];
rc = recvfrom(stun_socket, response, 64, 0, NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are doing something similar to this or equivalent for sending the data:

```
sendto(sock, &header, sizeof(header), (sockaddr*)&addr, addrlen);
```

If that's the case, you likely forgot to convert your message_type value to network byte order (big-endian).

Try this:

```
header.message_type = htons(0x0001);
```

But if you want a better solution, and you can use C++, use the client library built into [Stuntman](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver).  You can generate a binding request as follows with the C++ class, CStunMessageBuilder, declared in the [stuncore/stunbuilder.h](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/stuncore/stunbuilder.h) file.

```
CStunMessageBuilder builder;
StunTransactionId transId;

builder.AddBindingRequestHeader();
builder.AddRandomTransactionId(&transID);
unsigned char* msg = builder.GetStream().GetDataPointerUnsafe();
size_t len = builder.GetStream().GetSize();

sendto(sock, msg, len, (sockaddr*)&addr, addrlen);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get none response from the remote server. Have the piece of code pasted.

Comment: Get a tcpdump or a wireshark trace of your code running against the server and send me a link to it.

Comment: And go compile the code in the link above - such that you can compare your trace with the trace produced by running `stunclient stun.l.google.com 19305`

Comment: I didn't contain the magic cookie ^_^. And thanks for your help. That helped a lot. ^_^.